# Element not added into the right div with jquery- Infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to load a div i created with a function on the script and add it to the div=#posts but weird enough this never adds the items retrieve from the server to the div. The result is something like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/069Lk.jpg .

Here is the script:

```
var $container = $('#posts');
function createPost(title, body, image, id) {
    var x = '<div class="grid-item"><div class="blog-post">   <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/cba" alt="">  <h3>' + title + '</h3>  <img src="' + image + '" alt=""> <a href="../Blog/SearchPartial/' + id + '" class="btn btn-primary">Reload  </a> </div></div>"';
    $container.append(x)
};

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        alert("bottom!");
        InfiniteScroll();
    }
});


var PageCount = 2;
function InfiniteScroll() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../api/posts/" + PageCount,
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            if (data != "") {
                $.each(data, function (i, post) {
                    createPost(post.Title, post.Body, post.Image, post.ID)
                });
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert("error");
        }
    })
    PageCount++;
};
```

And here is the html:

```
<div id="posts"class="grid">
@foreach (var post in Model.Posts)
{
    <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="blog-post">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/cba" alt="">
            <h3>@post.Title</h3>
            <img src=@post.Image alt="">

            <a href='@Url.Action("SearchPartial","Blog",  new { postid = @post.ID })' class="button">
                Reload
            </a>
        </div>
   </div>
}
</div>
```

Comment: If it isn't actually loading appending anything to `#posts`, then you should -
**A-** check for errors in your console, and **B-** check to make sure `#posts` is loaded into the DOM before you assign it to your `$container` variable

Comment: And where is the json?

Comment: @Adjit there are no errors in console, it loads it just not in posts i didnt understand your second option

Comment: well the json is loading well @Dekel

Comment: I don't see anything in your question that display the json

Comment: @Dekel the json is normally loaded via the api  url: "../api/posts/" + PageCount,
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", this contains 
 blogposts

Comment: And where does the html fits?

Comment: var $container = $('#posts'); this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With masonry the appended value which was x on my code needs to be encapsulated as such:

```
var x = '<div class="grid-item"> <div class="blog-post">   <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/cba" alt="">  <h3>' + title + '</h3>  <img src="' + image + '" alt=""> <a href="../Blog/SearchPartial?postid=' + id + '" class="button">Read More </a> </div></div>"';

var $z = $(x);
$grid.masonry()
  .append($z)
  .masonry('appended', $z)
  .masonry();
```